# Browser.inputBox does not work in GoogleScript web app

Tags: google-apps-script

This code will work if I run my app in a spreadsheet

```
var name = Browser.inputBox("Enter your name");
```

But when I deployed it as a web app, it doesn't work. What other alternative can be used to capture information from a user in a GoogleScript web app?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Guide to UI Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp), and the [Guide to Html Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service) which introduce the two primary ways to create user interfaces for Google Apps WebApps.